# Linq to return all rows with the same (lowest) value

Tags: linq

I have a linq query that currently returns 1 product detail row for each product.

```
       return ProductDetailView
            .Select() // this is a method in repository
            .Where(x => x.MaxTerm >= days)
            .GroupBy(x => new { ID = x.ProductID })
            .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.MaxTerm).First())
            .OrderBy(x => (x.CostPer100 + x.FeesExcluded))
            .ToList();
```

This line orders the list by the product cost

```
            .OrderBy(x => (x.CostPer100 + x.FeesExcluded))
```

What I'd like to do is select all the rows that have the same value as the lowest cost - in other words take all rows until the value changes.

Is this even possible in 1 query?

Comment: It would be easier (and probably much more efficient) to figure out what the minimum value is then select all with that value.

Answer (score 0):

If you group by cost, then order the groups, the first group will contain all the rows that have the lowest cost:

```
return ProductDetailView
            .Select() // this is a method in repository
            .Where(x => x.MaxTerm >= days)
            .GroupBy(x => x.ProductID)
            .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.MaxTerm).FirstOrDefault())
            .GroupBy(x => (x.CostPer100 + x.FeesExcluded))
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .ToList();
```

But as Jeff Mercado suggested, it's probably more efficient to get the lowest cost, then do another query using that as a filter. Something like this:

```
var min = ProductDetailView
        .Select() // this is a method in repository
        .Where(x => x.MaxTerm >= days)
        .GroupBy(x => x.ProductID)
        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.MaxTerm).FirstOrDefault())
        .Min(x => (x.CostPer100 + x.FeesExcluded));

return ProductDetailView
        .Select() // this is a method in repository
        .Where(x => x.MaxTerm >= days && x.CostPer100 + x.FeesExcluded == min)
        .GroupBy(x => x.ProductID)
        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.MaxTerm).FirstOrDefault())
        .ToList();
```